# How to prepend or wrap each label and div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have this sequence of labels and `div`s and I need to wrap around each group of 1 label + 1 div another div. I know I have to use .each and `.wrap` or `.prepend` bu I need help. How can I do this?

HTML:

```html
<label>label</label>
<div>text</div>
<label>label</label>
<div>text</div>
```

**[Here I have set a jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/UNyeQ/)**

The result should be something like:

```html
<div class="1">
  <label>label</label>
  <div>text</div>
</div>
<div class="1">
  <label>label</label>
  <div>text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by iterating through the labels and wrapping/appending each:

```
$('label').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="l"/>').parent().next().appendTo($(this).parent());
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/UNyeQ/1/

Comment: In my production site, this was what worked. But all corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Or, use `.wrapAll()`.

```
$("label").each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.add($this.next()).wrapAll("<div class='1'/>");
});
```

[**See it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tW2Np/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this markup will always be this way:

```
$("label").each(function () {
  $(this).next("div").andSelf().wrapAll("<div>");
});
```

You could leave off the `"div"` of `.next`, but it prevents other elements from getting in the way.

http://jsfiddle.net/UNyeQ/3/

Comment: This one worked like a charm. I actually forgot an impportant part in the demo but this correct solved it. I hade some .clear divs in the middle. hehehe lucky this time.

Comment: Thanks @Explosion Pills. `wrapAll` was what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient way, but after lots of different tries, this is what I came up with:

```
$('label').each(function() {
  var next = $(this).nextAll('div')[0];
  $(this).wrap('<div class="new" />').append(next);
});
```

Everything else I tried which would select the label AND the div iterated though them separately, so it wouldn't pair them under the same div. The extra work there of saving the next `div` to a variable is because `nextAll()` operates on siblings of the same parent - presumably the `label` would become a child of the new `div` before `nextAll()` is evaluated, otherwise.